# shinymobile App: how to save image taken from webcam in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, shiny

im trying to make a shinymobile app with java extensions for js, the objetive is capture a image for make an ocr recognition with package tesseract, i need to save a temporarily file in format,("png","jpg"), i used a java code for activate webcam, take the photo and plot, but what i need to do is save this photo,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
    <script type="application/html-dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[3.4.1];shiny[1.4.0.2];bootstrap[3.4.1]</script>
    <script src="shared/json2-min.js"></script>
    <script src="shared/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="shared/shiny.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="shared/shiny.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="shared/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/respond.min.js"></script>  <script>// WebcamJS v1.0.25 - http://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs - MIT Licensed
(function(e){var t;function a(){var e=Error.apply(this,arguments);e.name=this.name="FlashError";this.stack=e.stack;this.message=e.message}function i(){var e=Error.apply(this,arguments);e.name=this.name="WebcamError";this.stack=e.stack;this.message=e.message}var s=function(){};s.prototype=Error.prototype;a.prototype=new s;i.prototype=new s;var Webcam={version:"1.0.25",protocol:location.protocol.match(/https/i)?"https":"http",loaded:false,live:false,userMedia:true,iOS:/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&!e.MSStream,params:{width:0,height:0,dest_width:0,dest_height:0,image_format:"jpeg",jpeg_quality:90,enable_flash:true,force_flash:false,flip_horiz:false,fps:30,upload_name:"webcam",constraints:null,swfURL:"",flashNotDetectedText:"ERROR: No Adobe Flash Player detected.  Webcam.js relies on Flash for browsers that do not support getUserMedia (like yours).",noInterfaceFoundText:"No supported webcam interface found.",unfreeze_snap:true,iosPlaceholderText:"Click here to open camera.",user_callback:null,user_canvas:null},errors:{FlashError:a,WebcamError:i},hooks:{},init:function(){var t=this;this.mediaDevices=navigator.mediaDevices&&navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia?navigator.mediaDevices:navigator.mozGetUserMedia||navigator.webkitGetUserMedia?{getUserMedia:function(e){return new Promise(function(t,a){(navigator.mozGetUserMedia||navigator.webkitGetUserMedia).call(navigator,e,t,a)})}}:null;e.URL=e.URL||e.webkitURL||e.mozURL||e.msURL;this.userMedia=this.userMedia&&!!this.mediaDevices&&!!e.URL;if(this.iOS){this.userMedia=null}if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox\D+(\d+)/)){if(parseInt(RegExp.$1,10)<21)this.userMedia=null}if(this.userMedia){e.addEventListener("beforeunload",function(e){t.reset()})}},exifOrientation:function(e){var t=new DataView(e);if(t.getUint8(0)!=255||t.getUint8(1)!=216){console.log("Not a valid JPEG file");return 0}var a=2;var i=null;while(a<e.byteLength){if(t.getUint8(a)!=255){console.log("Not a valid marker at offset "+a+", found: "+t.getUint8(a));return 0}i=t.getUint8(a+1);if(i==225){a+=4;var s="";for(n=0;n<4;n++){s+=String.fromCharCode(t.getUint8(a+n))}if(s!="Exif"){console.log("Not valid EXIF data found");return 0}a+=6;var r=null;if(t.getUint16(a)==18761){r=false}else if(t.getUint16(a)==19789){r=true}else{console.log("Not valid TIFF data! (no 0x4949 or 0x4D4D)");return 0}if(t.getUint16(a+2,!r)!=42){console.log("Not valid TIFF data! (no 0x002A)");return 0}var o=t.getUint32(a+4,!r);if(o<8){console.log("Not valid TIFF data! (First offset less than 8)",t.getUint32(a+4,!r));return 0}var l=a+o;var h=t.getUint16(l,!r);for(var c=0;c<h;c++){var d=l+c*12+2;if(t.getUint16(d,!r)==274){var f=t.getUint16(d+2,!r);var m=t.getUint32(d+4,!r);if(f!=3&&m!=1){console.log("Invalid EXIF orientation value type ("+f+") or count ("+m+")");return 0}var p=t.getUint16(d+8,!r);if(p<1||p>8){console.log("Invalid EXIF orientation value ("+p+")");return 0}return p}}}else{a+=2+t.getUint16(a+2)}}return 0},fixOrientation:function(e,t,a){var i=new Image;i.addEventListener("load",function(e){var s=document.createElement("canvas");var r=s.getContext("2d");if(t<5){s.width=i.width;s.height=i.height}else{s.width=i.height;s.height=i.width}switch(t){case 2:r.transform(-1,0,0,1,i.width,0);break;case 3:r.transform(-1,0,0,-1,i.width,i.height);break;case 4:r.transform(1,0,0,-1,0,i.height);break;case 5:r.transform(0,1,1,0,0,0);break;case 6:r.transform(0,1,-1,0,i.height,0);break;case 7:r.transform(0,-1,-1,0,i.height,i.width);break;case 8:r.transform(0,-1,1,0,0,i.width);break}r.drawImage(i,0,0);a.src=s.toDataURL()},false);i.src=e},attach:function(a){if(typeof a=="string"){a=document.getElementById(a)||document.querySelector(a)}if(!a){return this.dispatch("error",new i("Could not locate DOM element to attach to."))}this.container=a;a.innerHTML="";var s=document.createElement("div");a.appendChild(s);this.peg=s;if(!this.params.width)this.params.width=a.offsetWidth;if(!this.params.height)this.params.height=a.offsetHeight;if(!this.params.width||!this.params.height){return this.dispatch("error",new i("No width and/or height for webcam.  Please call set() first, or attach to a visible element."))}if(!this.params.dest_width)this.params.dest_width=this.params.width;if(!this.params.dest_height)this.params.dest_height=this.params.height;this.userMedia=t===undefined?this.userMedia:t;if(this.params.force_flash){t=this.userMedia;this.userMedia=null}if(typeof this.params.fps!=="number")this.params.fps=30;var r=this.params.width/this.params.dest_width;var o=this.params.height/this.params.dest_height;if(this.userMedia){var n=document.createElement("video");n.setAttribute("autoplay","autoplay");n.style.width=""+this.params.dest_width+"px";n.style.height=""+this.params.dest_height+"px";if(r!=1||o!=1){a.style.overflow="hidden";n.style.webkitTransformOrigin="0px 0px";n.style.mozTransformOrigin="0px 0px";n.style.msTransformOrigin="0px 0px";n.style.oTransformOrigin="0px 0px";n.style.transformOrigin="0px 0px";n.style.webkitTransform="scaleX("+r+") scaleY("+o+")";n.style.mozTransform="scaleX("+r+") scaleY("+o+")";n.style.msTransform="scaleX("+r+") scaleY("+o+")";n.style.oTransform="scaleX("+r+") scaleY("+o+")";n.style.transform="scaleX("+r+") scaleY("+o+")"}a.appendChild(n);this.video=n;var l=this;this.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:false,video:this.params.constraints||{mandatory:{minWidth:this.params.dest_width,minHeight:this.params.dest_height}}}).then(function(t){n.onloadedmetadata=function(e){l.stream=t;l.loaded=true;l.live=true;l.dispatch("load");l.dispatch("live");l.flip()};if("srcObject"in n){n.srcObject=t}else{n.src=e.URL.createObjectURL(t)}}).catch(function(e){if(l.params.enable_flash&&l.detectFlash()){setTimeout(function(){l.params.force_flash=1;l.attach(a)},1)}else{l.dispatch("error",e)}})}else if(this.iOS){var h=document.createElement("div");h.id=this.container.id+"-ios_div";h.className="webcamjs-ios-placeholder";h.style.width=""+this.params.width+"px";h.style.height=""+this.params.height+"px";h.style.textAlign="center";h.style.display="table-cell";h.style.verticalAlign="middle";h.style.backgroundRepeat="no-repeat";h.style.backgroundSize="contain";h.style.backgroundPosition="center";var c=document.createElement("span");c.className="webcamjs-ios-text";c.innerHTML=this.params.iosPlaceholderText;h.appendChild(c);var d=document.createElement("img");d.id=this.container.id+"-ios_img";d.style.width=""+this.params.dest_width+"px";d.style.height=""+this.params.dest_height+"px";d.style.display="none";h.appendChild(d);var f=document.createElement("input");f.id=this.container.id+"-ios_input";f.setAttribute("type","file");f.setAttribute("accept","image/*");f.setAttribute("capture","camera");var l=this;var m=this.params;f.addEventListener("change",function(e){if(e.target.files.length>0&&e.target.files[0].type.indexOf("image/")==0){var t=URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);var a=new Image;a.addEventListener("load",function(e){var t=document.createElement("canvas");t.width=m.dest_width;t.height=m.dest_height;var i=t.getContext("2d");ratio=Math.min(a.width/m.dest_width,a.height/m.dest_height);var s=m.dest_width*ratio;var r=m.dest_height*ratio;var o=(a.width-s)/2;var n=(a.height-r)/2;i.drawImage(a,o,n,s,r,0,0,m.dest_width,m.dest_height);var l=t.toDataURL();d.src=l;h.style.backgroundImage="url('"+l+"')"},false);var i=new FileReader;i.addEventListener("load",function(e){var i=l.exifOrientation(e.target.result);if(i>1){l.fixOrientation(t,i,a)}else{a.src=t}},false);var s=new XMLHttpRequest;s.open("GET",t,true);s.responseType="blob";s.onload=function(e){if(this.status==200||this.status===0){i.readAsArrayBuffer(this.response)}};s.send()}},false);f.style.display="none";a.appendChild(f);h.addEventListener("click",function(e){if(m.user_callback){l.snap(m.user_callback,m.user_canvas)}else{f.style.display="block";f.focus();f.click();f.style.display="none"}},false);a.appendChild(h);this.loaded=true;this.live=true}else if(this.params.enable_flash&&this.detectFlash()){e.Webcam=Webcam;var h=document.createElement("div");h.innerHTML=this.getSWFHTML();a.appendChild(h)}else{this.dispatch("error",new i(this.params.noInterfaceFoundText))}if(this.params.crop_width&&this.params.crop_height){var p=Math.floor(this.params.crop_width*r);var u=Math.floor(this.params.crop_height*o);a.style.width=""+p+"px";a.style.height=""+u+"px";a.style.overflow="hidden";a.scrollLeft=Math.floor(this.params.width/2-p/2);a.scrollTop=Math.floor(this.params.height/2-u/2)}else{a.style.width=""+this.params.width+"px";a.style.height=""+this.params.height+"px"}},reset:function(){if(this.preview_active)this.unfreeze();this.unflip();if(this.userMedia){if(this.stream){if(this.stream.getVideoTracks){var e=this.stream.getVideoTracks();if(e&&e[0]&&e[0].stop)e[0].stop()}else if(this.stream.stop){this.stream.stop()}}delete this.stream;delete this.video}if(this.userMedia!==true&&this.loaded&&!this.iOS){var t=this.getMovie();if(t&&t._releaseCamera)t._releaseCamera()}if(this.container){this.container.innerHTML="";delete this.container}this.loaded=false;this.live=false},set:function(){if(arguments.length==1){for(var e in arguments[0]){this.params[e]=arguments[0][e]}}else{this.params[arguments[0]]=arguments[1]}},on:function(e,t){e=e.replace(/^on/i,"").toLowerCase();if(!this.hooks[e])this.hooks[e]=[];this.hooks[e].push(t)},off:function(e,t){e=e.replace(/^on/i,"").toLowerCase();if(this.hooks[e]){if(t){var a=this.hooks[e].indexOf(t);if(a>-1)this.hooks[e].splice(a,1)}else{this.hooks[e]=[]}}},dispatch:function(){var t=arguments[0].replace(/^on/i,"").toLowerCase();var s=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);if(this.hooks[t]&&this.hooks[t].length){for(var r=0,o=this.hooks[t].length;r<o;r++){var n=this.hooks[t][r];if(typeof n=="function"){n.apply(this,s)}else if(typeof n=="object"&&n.length==2){n[0][n[1]].apply(n[0],s)}else if(e[n]){e[n].apply(e,s)}}return true}else if(t=="error"){var l;if(s[0]instanceof a||s[0]instanceof i){l=s[0].message}else{l="Could not access webcam: "+s[0].name+": "+s[0].message+" "+s[0].toString()}alert("Webcam.js Error: "+l)}return false},setSWFLocation:function(e){this.set("swfURL",e)},detectFlash:function(){var t="Shockwave Flash",a="ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash",i="application/x-shockwave-flash",s=e,r=navigator,o=false;if(typeof r.plugins!=="undefined"&&typeof r.plugins[t]==="object"){var n=r.plugins[t].description;if(n&&(typeof r.mimeTypes!=="undefined"&&r.mimeTypes[i]&&r.mimeTypes[i].enabledPlugin)){o=true}}else if(typeof s.ActiveXObject!=="undefined"){try{var l=new ActiveXObject(a);if(l){var h=l.GetVariable("$version");if(h)o=true}}catch(e){}}return o},getSWFHTML:function(){var t="",i=this.params.swfURL;if(location.protocol.match(/file/)){this.dispatch("error",new a("Flash does not work from local disk.  Please run from a web server."));return'<h3 style="color:red">ERROR: the Webcam.js Flash fallback does not work from local disk.  Please run it from a web server.</h3>'}if(!this.detectFlash()){this.dispatch("error",new a("Adobe Flash Player not found.  Please install from get.adobe.com/flashplayer and try again."));return'<h3 style="color:red">'+this.params.flashNotDetectedText+"</h3>"}if(!i){var s="";var r=document.getElementsByTagName("script");for(var o=0,n=r.length;o<n;o++){var l=r[o].getAttribute("src");if(l&&l.match(/\/webcam(\.min)?\.js/)){s=l.replace(/\/webcam(\.min)?\.js.*$/,"");o=n}}if(s)i=s+"/webcam.swf";else i="webcam.swf"}if(e.localStorage&&!localStorage.getItem("visited")){this.params.new_user=1;localStorage.setItem("visited",1)}var h="";for(var c in this.params){if(h)h+="&";h+=c+"="+escape(this.params[c])}t+='<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" codebase="'+this.protocol+'://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="'+this.params.width+'" height="'+this.params.height+'" id="webcam_movie_obj" align="middle"><param name="wmode" value="opaque" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" /><param name="movie" value="'+i+'" /><param name="loop" value="false" /><param name="menu" value="false" /><param name="quality" value="best" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /><param name="flashvars" value="'+h+'"/><embed id="webcam_movie_embed" src="'+i+'" wmode="opaque" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="'+this.params.width+'" height="'+this.params.height+'" name="webcam_movie_embed" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="'+h+'"></embed></object>';return t},getMovie:function(){if(!this.loaded)return this.dispatch("error",new a("Flash Movie is not loaded yet"));var e=document.getElementById("webcam_movie_obj");if(!e||!e._snap)e=document.getElementById("webcam_movie_embed");if(!e)this.dispatch("error",new a("Cannot locate Flash movie in DOM"));return e},freeze:function(){var e=this;var t=this.params;if(this.preview_active)this.unfreeze();var a=this.params.width/this.params.dest_width;var i=this.params.height/this.params.dest_height;this.unflip();var s=t.crop_width||t.dest_width;var r=t.crop_height||t.dest_height;var o=document.createElement("canvas");o.width=s;o.height=r;var n=o.getContext("2d");this.preview_canvas=o;this.preview_context=n;if(a!=1||i!=1){o.style.webkitTransformOrigin="0px 0px";o.style.mozTransformOrigin="0px 0px";o.style.msTransformOrigin="0px 0px";o.style.oTransformOrigin="0px 0px";o.style.transformOrigin="0px 0px";o.style.webkitTransform="scaleX("+a+") scaleY("+i+")";o.style.mozTransform="scaleX("+a+") scaleY("+i+")";o.style.msTransform="scaleX("+a+") scaleY("+i+")";o.style.oTransform="scaleX("+a+") scaleY("+i+")";o.style.transform="scaleX("+a+") scaleY("+i+")"}this.snap(function(){o.style.position="relative";o.style.left=""+e.container.scrollLeft+"px";o.style.top=""+e.container.scrollTop+"px";e.container.insertBefore(o,e.peg);e.container.style.overflow="hidden";e.preview_active=true},o)},unfreeze:function(){if(this.preview_active){this.container.removeChild(this.preview_canvas);delete this.preview_context;delete this.preview_canvas;this.preview_active=false;this.flip()}},flip:function(){if(this.params.flip_horiz){var e=this.container.style;e.webkitTransform="scaleX(-1)";e.mozTransform="scaleX(-1)";e.msTransform="scaleX(-1)";e.oTransform="scaleX(-1)";e.transform="scaleX(-1)";e.filter="FlipH";e.msFilter="FlipH"}},unflip:function(){if(this.params.flip_horiz){var e=this.container.style;e.webkitTransform="scaleX(1)";e.mozTransform="scaleX(1)";e.msTransform="scaleX(1)";e.oTransform="scaleX(1)";e.transform="scaleX(1)";e.filter="";e.msFilter=""}},savePreview:function(e,t){var a=this.params;var i=this.preview_canvas;var s=this.preview_context;if(t){var r=t.getContext("2d");r.drawImage(i,0,0)}e(t?null:i.toDataURL("image/"+a.image_format,a.jpeg_quality/100),i,s);if(this.params.unfreeze_snap)this.unfreeze()},snap:function(e,t){if(!e)e=this.params.user_callback;if(!t)t=this.params.user_canvas;var a=this;var s=this.params;if(!this.loaded)return this.dispatch("error",new i("Webcam is not loaded yet"));if(!e)return this.dispatch("error",new i("Please provide a callback function or canvas to snap()"));if(this.preview_active){this.savePreview(e,t);return null}var r=document.createElement("canvas");r.width=this.params.dest_width;r.height=this.params.dest_height;var o=r.getContext("2d");if(this.params.flip_horiz){o.translate(s.dest_width,0);o.scale(-1,1)}var n=function(){if(this.src&&this.width&&this.height){o.drawImage(this,0,0,s.dest_width,s.dest_height)}if(s.crop_width&&s.crop_height){var a=document.createElement("canvas");a.width=s.crop_width;a.height=s.crop_height;var i=a.getContext("2d");i.drawImage(r,Math.floor(s.dest_width/2-s.crop_width/2),Math.floor(s.dest_height/2-s.crop_height/2),s.crop_width,s.crop_height,0,0,s.crop_width,s.crop_height);o=i;r=a}if(t){var n=t.getContext("2d");n.drawImage(r,0,0)}e(t?null:r.toDataURL("image/"+s.image_format,s.jpeg_quality/100),r,o)};if(this.userMedia){o.drawImage(this.video,0,0,this.params.dest_width,this.params.dest_height);n()}else if(this.iOS){var l=document.getElementById(this.container.id+"-ios_div");var h=document.getElementById(this.container.id+"-ios_img");var c=document.getElementById(this.container.id+"-ios_input");iFunc=function(e){n.call(h);h.removeEventListener("load",iFunc);l.style.backgroundImage="none";h.removeAttribute("src");c.value=null};if(!c.value){h.addEventListener("load",iFunc);c.style.display="block";c.focus();c.click();c.style.display="none"}else{iFunc(null)}}else{var d=this.getMovie()._snap();var h=new Image;h.onload=n;h.src="data:image/"+this.params.image_format+";base64,"+d}return null},configure:function(e){if(!e)e="camera";this.getMovie()._configure(e)},flashNotify:function(e,t){switch(e){case"flashLoadComplete":this.loaded=true;this.dispatch("load");break;case"cameraLive":this.live=true;this.dispatch("live");break;case"error":this.dispatch("error",new a(t));break;default:break}},b64ToUint6:function(e){return e>64&&e<91?e-65:e>96&&e<123?e-71:e>47&&e<58?e+4:e===43?62:e===47?63:0},base64DecToArr:function(e,t){var a=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/]/g,""),i=a.length,s=t?Math.ceil((i*3+1>>2)/t)*t:i*3+1>>2,r=new Uint8Array(s);for(var o,n,l=0,h=0,c=0;c<i;c++){n=c&3;l|=this.b64ToUint6(a.charCodeAt(c))<<18-6*n;if(n===3||i-c===1){for(o=0;o<3&&h<s;o++,h++){r[h]=l>>>(16>>>o&24)&255}l=0}}return r},upload:function(e,t,a){var i=this.params.upload_name||"webcam";var s="";if(e.match(/^data\:image\/(\w+)/))s=RegExp.$1;else throw"Cannot locate image format in Data URI";var r=e.replace(/^data\:image\/\w+\;base64\,/,"");var o=new XMLHttpRequest;o.open("POST",t,true);if(o.upload&&o.upload.addEventListener){o.upload.addEventListener("progress",function(e){if(e.lengthComputable){var t=e.loaded/e.total;Webcam.dispatch("uploadProgress",t,e)}},false)}var n=this;o.onload=function(){if(a)a.apply(n,[o.status,o.responseText,o.statusText]);Webcam.dispatch("uploadComplete",o.status,o.responseText,o.statusText)};var l=new Blob([this.base64DecToArr(r)],{type:"image/"+s});var h=new FormData;h.append(i,l,i+"."+s.replace(/e/,""));o.send(h)}};Webcam.init();if(typeof define==="function"&&define.amd){define(function(){return Webcam})}else if(typeof module==="object"&&module.exports){module.exports=Webcam}else{e.Webcam=Webcam}})(window);</script>
    <div id="my_camera"></div>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        Webcam.set({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            image_format: 'jpeg',
            jpeg_quality: 100
        });
        Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
    </script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <button id="react" type="button" onClick="take_snapshot()" class="btn btn-default action-button" style="padding:8px; font-size:90%;color: #fff; background-color: #6099d1; border-color: white">
        <i class="fa fa-glasses"></i>
        Escanear QR
    </button>
    <div id="snap" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

i need your help in order to complete my improve

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you required to use Java? Because if not, then you can simply use built-in JavaScript APIs to use the webcam and save the picture as a file on the Client's computer.